# Primary key identifier difference between Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on a DB-first environment with a .NET application.

I realized when I create migration files, Entity Framework does not pick up the correct primary key name from SQL Server when it needs to drop a primary key.

This is what the migration file generates to drop the primary key:

```
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.TableName");
```

But in SQL Server, the PK constraint is like this:

```
[PK__TableName__48AFA797B7F88EC3]
```

I have two questions:

- Why does the PK constraint have these randomly generated numbers in the name?
- Why can Entity Framework not detect that name and create a migration file according to the current schema?

When I run the migration file contains `DropPrimaryKey("dbo.TableName");` it doesn't work and I get this error:

> 'PK_dbo.TableName' is not a constraint.
> Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why PK has these randomly generated numbers in the name?

If you don't name the constraint, SQL Server will generate a name for it.

> When I run the migration file  . . .

Why are you even generating migrations?  In a database-first workflow you apply schema changes directly to the database and then re-scaffold or adjust the EF model to match.  Migrations are only used in a code-first workflow.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Following up on your reply to my second question, all tables are generated with the db-first approach because of an existing db. But after db and tables in the code are synced, whenever we need to make a change in any table, we make the change on the entity, create migrations, and then ef applies changes on the db. So it is code first approach at this point if I am not mistaken. Do you think shifting from the database first to code first in this scenario is wrong?

Comment: It's reasonable to switch for database-first to code-first.  But you'll need to do some cleanup so that the database looks like the code expects it to look.